# Can i post raw data and some other type of data when i post request?

Tags: php, rest, postman

I have an Rest Api that i can basically do crud operations.

When I test the routes with postman, i am using raw json data when i do post request.

My scenerio is there are campaigns and one campaign have multiple assets. So for now i can only create campaign with its details coming from raw json data.

But i created new table called assets which has a relationship with campaigns and it stores only asset type and campaign id. Si i want to refactor my create method in my controller so that when i create campaign and insert into campaigns table, also i want to insert asset type into assets table.

But in frontend, there will be multiple selection selectbox for selecting asset types. So if user select 2 of the types, there will be inserted those selections seperately.

Also how can i pass this data from selectbox to backend? Can i pass this like raw data that i did before for campaign details? Here is my create method in my controller:

```
public function createCampaign($input)
    {
        if (empty($input->name) || empty($input->description) || empty($input->status) || empty($input->start_date) || empty($input->end_date) || empty($input->discount)) {
            return new ErrorModel([
                'code' => 400,
                'errorDetails' => 'Please provide all the required fields'
            ]);
        }

        $campaignModuleModel = new CampaignModuleModel([
            'name' => $input->name,
            'description' => $input->description,
            'status' => $input->status,
            'start_date' => $input->start_date,
            'end_date' => $input->end_date,
            'discount' => $input->discount
        ]);

        $data = $this->sdk()->db()->insert($campaignModuleModel);

        if (!$data) {
            return new ErrorModel([
                'code' => 400,
                'errorDetails' => 'There was an error creating the campaign'
            ]);
        }

        return $this->sdk()->db()->select($campaignModuleModel);
    }
```

In short, I am struggling with how to pass data from selectbox and insert into db those multiple selection one by one into table. Can help me with this issue?
Edited:
Also in postman i am posting data like this:
[image]

Comment: You can pass multiple data in an array.

Comment: @OMiShah so can i pass data like assets_type array in raw json data as i did in the picture?

Comment: for example JSON: ``[ {"name": "XYZ", "asset_type": "typ1", ... }, {"name": "XYZ", "asset_type": "typ2"}, ... ]``

Comment: @OMiShah But i want to insert seperately how can i do that in code base?

Comment: After receiving the JSON, loop the JSON array and store it individually as you're doing.